# Datetime from strings with microseconds

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, time, strptime

How to include microseconds to datetime, for example:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-08-30 15:02:55.730', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

>>> ValueError: unconverted data remains: .730
```

I want to have microseconds too. What should format string look like? What is the placeholder for microseconds?

Comment: .xxx is milliseconds. .xxxxxx is microseconds.  (Luckily, %f handles both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-08-30 15:02:55.730', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

you can look at:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior